# jquery appendTo html ordering issue

Tags: jquery

I have the code below that appends a question/answer to a div.

It works, but it's writing to the div in the wrong order.  It's putting any new divs BEFORE the last one, so the numbering becomes out of order like this:

```
Question 3
Question 2
Question 1
```

I played around with appendTo, append, but anything I do does not work.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Here's the code:

```
$(".questionButton").click(function () {
var parentId = $("button").closest("div").attr("id");
var newTextBoxDiv = $("<div>").attr("id", 'question' + questionCounter);
        $(this).after(newTextBoxDiv);
        newTextBoxDiv.after().html(
            "<table><tr>" +
            "<td>" +
            "<label>Question " + questionCounter + ": </label>" +
            "</td><td>" +
            "<input type='text' name='tbQuestion' id='tbQuestion" + questionCounter + "' value='' >" +
            "</td>" +
            "<td class='removeQuestion'>x</td>" +
            "</tr><tr><td>" +
            "<label>Answer: </label>" +
            "</td><td>" +
            "<input type='text' name='tbAnswer'" id='tbAnswer" + questionCounter + "' value='' >" +
            "</td></tr></table>");
        newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#" + parentId);
        questionCounter++;
});
```

html:

```
<div id="questionBox">
    <div id="mcq" style="display: none;" class="questionTypeDiv">
        <input type="button" class="questionButton" value="Add Question" style="margin-top: 4px;" />
        <table></table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does [prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) put them in the right order?

Comment: Can you provide [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net) example?

Comment: What does `$(this)` refer to?  You need to post all of your code, we can't help you based on what you've provided at all.

Comment: I can tell you that:  `newTextBoxDiv.after().html(` doesn't look right at all.

Comment: You're only supposed to use `.after()` to insert content like this:  `after('content here')`  - you can't use it as you've used it.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions...I added the HTML code

Comment: Can you post your entire loop? You've got some serious code smells and `appendTo` [appends to the end](http://jsfiddle.net/2sRD2/).

Comment: sorry, there is no loop...it just adds a new question/answer group whenever the button is pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mistakenly appending the div after the button, rather than your `<div id="mcq">`: http://jsfiddle.net/ZTuhn/1/

You could also fix this error by selecting the preceding question id correctly and then appending after that. However, this would require some exception handling for your initial questionBox id attribute.

Answer (score -1):

To append in order, you should use .append() like so:

```
$.each([1,2,3], function(i,v) {
    $('#' + parentId).append('<p>Question ' + v + '</p>')
});
```